# why there is lib and bin in dart projects

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been using dart projects in order to practice dart programs and wondered why there are two folders `bin` and `lib` both can contain dart files.

I did some research about this and they said `bin` folder is for creating console application but that didn't help me. I don't have a clear idea about console application.
and why should I bother about these folder if I'm only using dart projects just for practicing dart language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `bin` folder** is where you put the public entrypoints for your project to compile it to executable binaries for console applications.

If you are just practing dart code, you can leave it there and just use the `lib` folder. Just make sure you'll have a file inside `bin` with the same name as the project/package you created (defined in `pubspec.yaml`) and a `main()` function, so you can use `dart run`.

**The `lib` folder** is for all the other code you write. You can add in there all your classes files of your project as a additional code to be called by the files from the `bin` folder. Or you can use just the `lib` folder to write a package/library for other apps, without needing to have a `bin` folder.

---

But the `bin` folder can have a file for each command, with a `main()` inside each file.

For example, you could have in it `bin/sum.dart` and `bin/subtract.dart`. Then you can compile each to a executable binary (sum.exe and subtract.exe) to use it as a command-line/console program.

To [run each file without compiling](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-run#in-the-current-package) just use `dart run :COMMAND` (in the example above, `dart run :sum`).

If you want to know more about it, see the documentation explaining [how to compile](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started#6-compile-for-production) and [how to write a package that has a command-line tool](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#providing-additional-files)